# Restrict access to directory based on protocol

Tags: .htaccess, ssh

I know `.htaccess` can be used to restrict access to specific directories based on domain, IP address, etc. but is there a way I can restrict access based on protocol?

I have some scripts I want to be able to run remotely on an Apache server *only* from SSH.

Comment: Why are the scripts under access from httpd, is that necessary?

Comment: @JGK not necessary, no. Just curious about the general feasibility of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Ssh and http(s) are completely different protocols and usually different server-side programs are responsible for them.

The Apache httpd serves http and if configured https requests. Restricting access can be done with `.htaccess` files. In a `.htaccess` https usage can be forced with the [SSLRequireSSL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl) directive. The Apache httpd has nothing to do with ssh.

For ssh connections generally the sshd is responsible and therefor if you want to access and execute your scripts only over ssh, move them out of httpd access.